# Disable Chrome Web Security On Chromebook

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I know how to disable chrome web security flag on Windows. But I'm on chromebook and have no idea how to disable XSS Auditor aka chrome web security flag on chromebook for pentesting.

Please help! Thanks!

Edit: This question address the fact that I want to disable security flags on chromebook, not android webview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I installed crouton and then used `--disable-web-security` flag. This can be done by installing ubuntu or any other linux distro and then using chromium there.

Chromebook natively does not support disabling web security flag.

Answer (score 0):

Now that Chromebooks support Linux. I "turned on" the Linux feature and installed Chrome inside the Linux container. I then used the command below to launch Chrome with Web security disabled.

```
google-chrome --user-data-dir=”/var/tmp/Chrome” --disable-web-security
```

Seems Chromebooks don't allow users to disable web security natively.